# Read/write binary data on SD using Arduino

Tags: arduino, sd-card

I'm working on a project with an Arduino, and I'd like to be able to save some data persistently. I'm already using an Ethernet shield, which has a MicroSD reader.

The data I'm saving will be incredibly small. At the moment, I'll just be saving 3 bytes at a time. What I'd really like is a way to open the SD card for writing starting at byte `x` and then write `y` bytes of data. When I want to read it back, I just read `y` bytes starting at byte `x`.

However, all the code I've seen involves working with a filesystem, which seems like an unneeded overhead. I don't need this data to be readable on any other system, storage space isn't an issue, and there's no other data on the card to worry about. Is there a way to just write binary data directly to an SD card?

Comment: Checkout http://www.roland-riegel.de/sd-reader/ for raw SD card read/write routines. FAQ section says it is possible to use it for  Arduino with some changes.

Comment: Another good resource for binary SD card read/ write on Arduino: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/fast-efficient-data-storage-on-an-arduino/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to write raw binary data to an SD card. Most people do this using the 4-pin SPI interface supported by the SD card. Unfortunately, data isn't byte-addressed, but block-addressed (block size usually 512 bytes).

This means if you wanted to write 4 bytes at byte 516, you'd have to read in block 0x00000001 (the second block), and then calculate an offset, write your data, then write the entire block back. (I can't say that this limitation applies to the SD interface using more pins, I have no experience with it)

This complication is why a lot of people opt for using libraries that include "unneeded overhead".

With that said, I've had to do this in the past, because I needed a way of logging data that was robust in the face of power failures. I found the following resource very helpful:

http://elm-chan.org/docs/mmc/mmc_e.html

You'll probably find it easier to make your smaller writes to a memory buffer, and dump them to the SD card when you have a large enough amount of data to make it worthwhile.

If you look around, you'll find plenty of open-source code dealing with the SD SPI interface to make use of directly, or as reference to implement your own system.

Comment: Hi can you tell me how to find the total number of blocks available on sd card ?

Comment: You can get that value from the CSD register.